# PHP processing form : unknown sender

Tags: php, email

I created a form with a processing PHP file. Everything works fine. I receive the mail but it's from "Unknow sender" in Gmail. Why please ?

I would like to see in my email box the name and the firstname of the person who fills the form. What's wrong in my code ?

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['form3_firstname']) && isset($_POST['form3_name']) && isset($_POST['form3_email']) && isset($_POST['form3_telephone']) && isset($_POST['form3_message'])) {
    extract($_POST);
    if(!empty($form3_firstname) && !empty($form3_name) && !empty($form3_email) && !empty($form3_telephone) && !empty($form3_message)) {

        $to = 'XXXXXX@gmail.com'; // My real email

        $subject = 'Contact from the site';

        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From:' .$form3_firstname. " " .$form3_name. "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To:'.$form3_email. "\r\n";

        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>';
        $message .= '<table>';
        $message .= '<tr><td colspan="2"><p>MESSAGE</p></td></tr>';
        $message .= '<tr><td>Firstname :</td><td>'.$form3_firstname.'</td></tr>';
        $message .= '<tr><td>Name :</td><td>'.$form3_name.'</td></tr>';
        $message .= '<tr><td>Email :</td><td>'.$form3_email.'</td></tr>';
        $message .= '<tr><td>Telephone :</td><td>'.$form3_telephone.'</td></tr>';
        $message .= '<tr><td>Message :</td<td>'.stripslashes($form3_message).'</td></tr>';
        $message .= '</table>';
        $message .= '</body></html>';


        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo "Form sent";
        } else {
            echo "Form not sent";
        }

    } else {
        echo "You have not filled in the field";
    }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `$form3_name` with `$form3_email`

```
$headers .= 'From:' .$form3_firstname. " " .$form3_name. "\r\n";
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ //<----- Here
```

That's a name , not an email address , and that's the reason you get that error.

Also, you need to wrap them in tags `<>`

#### The right way..

```
$headers .= 'From:' .$form3_firstname. " ".'<'.$form3_email.'>'."\r\n";
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I thought I could bring up the name and surname.

Comment: Instead you can concatenate them (first name and surname) separately in a variable and add that in the place of `$form3_firstname` above.

Comment: Unfortunately I got always "Unknow sender" with this code : $headers .= 'From:' .$form3_firstname. " ".'<'.$form3_name.'>'."\r\n";

Comment: @Xroad, It should be `$form_email`. Like this `$headers .= 'From:' .$form3_firstname. " ".'<'.$form3_email.'>'."\r\n";`

Comment: I see the part before the at sign. Example my name is Brandon Mickael and my email is thechampion@domain.com I see "thechampion" and no Brandon Mickael.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($form3_email);` and see if the email id is proper ?

Comment: Yeah I got : string 'xx@hotmail.fr' (length=14)

Answer (score 1):

replace `"\r\n"` with `"\n"` and your problem will be solved... and also put `return-path` in your headers...

```
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\n";
    $headers .= 'From: \''.$form3_firstname.'\' <'.$form3_firstname.'>\r\nReturn-Path: <'.$form3_firstname.'>
    $headers .= 'From:' .$form3_firstname. " " .$form3_name. "\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To:'.$form3_email. "\n";
```

please let me know if you want furtther guidance...

Comment: Thank you but with your code I don't longer receive emails.

Comment: @Xroad sorry.. in `<'.$form3_firstname.'>` you need to put `email`.. I missed it... :P

Comment: The <'.$form3_firstname.'> after Return-Path ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not supply an emailaddress in your "From:" header. There always needs to be an emailaddress.

Try something like: 
 $headers .= "From: $form3_firstname $form3_name <$form_email>\r\n";

Mind you, you may have to test and/or escape your form variables; for instance, check that there is no newline in there, otherwise your form might be abused for spamming.

Comment: You're welcome. If it works don't forget to mark the chosen solution as the answer, so that the topic is closed or at least marked as "answered:. Also: if your form is not behind a login (and sometimes also when it is): mark my words about the spam-test. You do NOT want to become the target of SPAM-sending robots via your form. This is a very realistic threat. You will get tons of email, your emailaddress will be blacklisted, and more misery.

Comment: Well I don't have find the solution. You advice me to put a captcha system ?